# pass the values of a tensor to the lower traingular part of 2 dimentional tensor

Tags: python, r, tensorflow, keras

I am new in **Python** and **Tensorflow** and I am working on a project in **Python**. Assume I have vector  **X**,

> X=[x1,x2,x3]

and want to convert it to a lower triangular matrix **A** with one in the main diagonal,

> A=[ [ 1, 0, 0] , [ x1, 1, 0], [ x2, x3, 1] ].

In **R** I used this simple code:

```
A<-diag(3)
A[lower.tri(A)] <- X.
```

In my project, **X** is a tensor, as the output of a Neural network in **Tensorflow**.

```
X <- layer_dense(hidden layer, dec_dim)
```

So, I want to do that in Keras or Tensorflow same as before if it is possible. For example in Keras,

```
from keras import backend as K
 A= K.eye(3)
```

But I could not find a solution in Tensorflow or Keras for the second command. I would not like to use the ***For*** loop here because of the running time. Is there any short solution for that? Do you have any idea about that? Thanks beforehand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to get all indices for `X` and apply them to `A`.

```
from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow as tf

n = 3
X = tf.constant([1,2,3],tf.float32)
A = K.eye(n)

column,row = tf.meshgrid(tf.range(n),tf.range(n))
indices = tf.where(tf.less(column,row))
# [[1 0]
#  [2 0]
#  [2 1]]

A = tf.scatter_nd(indices,X,(n,n)) + A
# if your lower triangular part of A not equal 0, you can use follow code.
# tf.matrix_band_part(A, 0, -1)==> Upper triangular part
# A = tf.scatter_nd(indices,X,(n,n)) + tf.matrix_band_part(A, 0, -1)

print(K.eval(A))
# [[1. 0. 0.]
#  [1. 1. 0.]
#  [2. 3. 1.]]
```